# Hubbard–Stratonovich for matrices

Tags: matrices, gaussian

1. Can somebody share a link to papers( books) where this fornula was deduced?
   $e^{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}K_{ij}s_is_j} =\left(\frac{\det{K}}{(2\pi)^N} \right)^{1/2} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}...\int^{\infty}_{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^Nd\phi_k \exp{\left[-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}\phi_i K_{ij}\phi_j + \sum_{ij} s_iK_{ij}\phi_j\right]}$

where $K$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix
2. What is if K is negative? I think the following
$e^{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}(-|K_{ij}|s_is_j)} =\left(\frac{\det{K}}{(2\pi)^N} \right)^{1/2} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}...\int^{\infty}_{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^Nd\phi_k \exp{\left[-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}\phi_i K_{ij}\phi_j + i\sum_{ij} s_iK_{ij}\phi_j\right]}$

Comment: 1) this is a simple exercise of [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square); 2) the integral over $\phi_k$ does not converge for negative $K$.